# Linq To Entity Not Working

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three poco classes in my model domain as bellow 
everything works fine i can do crud operation for all three one , but in customer index view or detail view,  i want to count the number of orders and sum of service rate field , i run the following queries but they always return zero

in index view

```
 @item.Orders.Count
 @item.Orders.Sum(O=>O.Service.Rate)
```

and in detail view

```
  @Model.Orders.Count
  @Model.Orders.Sum(o=>o.Service.Rate)
```

i have also tried to use linq in controller with viewBag but it retrun zero

```
 ViewBag.RateX = customer.Orders.Count;
 ViewBag.Sum = customer.Orders.Sum(o => o.Service.Rate);
```

i have looked in Order table in sql , there exist both customerID and ProductID in table with  primary key value of customer and service table .

i have already search msdn and google but couldnt find what is wrong ?

```
 public class Customer



{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public String CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public String FistName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Mobile { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

}
```

}

```
  public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter Product Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Pleas Eneter A Rate For this Product")]
    public int Rate { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
 public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public Product Service { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("customer")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
}
```

}
here is customer controller 
     public ActionResult Index()
        {

```
        return View(db.Customers.ToList());
    }
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
       var order = from s in db.Orders where s.customer.CustomerID == customer.CustomerID select s;
       var rate = order.Sum(o => o.Service.Rate);
       ViewBag.Rate = rate;
       ViewBag.RateX = customer.Orders.Count;
       ViewBag.Sum = customer.Orders.Sum(o => o.Service.Rate);
        return View(customer);
    }
```

thanks a lot .

Comment: i added virtual accessor to  public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } it is working ,now t i have problem with sum of product rate for customer , let me see if i can fix it .then i will answer my own question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well What Actually i was doing is called lazy loading

In case EF Support lazy loading i should have been adding virtual keyword to my classess as below

in order class

```
public virtual Product Service { get; set; }
```

and in customer class

```
 public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```